# Migrate a custom button that uses javascript to lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am new to lightning. I need to migrate a custom button on record detail page that uses javascript to lightning. I tried creating a lightning action using lightning component. It worked fine but still the page did not get refreshed.

Also is there a way to create a lightning button for the same. The logic that needs to be implemented is below:
The custom button is on Case object. On clicking it , the case fields and its child records needs to be updated.

Any other approach using process builder is also welcome!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vivek.

I tried using 
`<lightning:button>` instead of <`ui:button>` and it worked.The page got refreshed. However  I have included the

```
 <aura: handler>
```

event as well.

Answer (score 0):

i do not have commenting available. so i need to ask here.
What actually By fields and child record Update means. Do you want to relaod the page and reflect the changes if any occured ?

If that is an Scenario you need to add this to your component.

```
 <aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="" />
```